# Php date_diff inbuilt function example code

Tags: php, date

Can any once suggest me date_diff function working syntax,

```
My code try
$date1="12-02-2104";
$date2="12-02-2104";
   echo date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

This did not gave me any result.

Comment: Go **read the [manual](http://php.net/date_diff)**

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: please read http://php.net/date_diff

Comment: Is [**this**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#refsect1-datetime.diff-examples) example really that tough ??

Comment: @Hamza.sorry was working on it without reading php date manual. don't down vote please, will remove this question if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

Comment: @HamZa i will take care of this from next time :)